# Breaking up CSV Files

Tags: powershell, csv

So I am looking at breaking up a CSV using Powershell. The CSV is delmited by | which isn't a problem, and I am looking to break it up into multiple smaller csvs while retaining the original. The breaks would occur based off of the value in a single column containing one of a list of values.
What I have done so far is to import the csv (delimited by |) and then

```
foreach($line in $csv)  {  
if($columnValue -like $target1) {  
export-csv filename1.csv -Delimiter `| $line -append)} 
elseif($columnValue -like $target2) { 
export-csv filename2.csv -Delimiter `| $line -append)}
```

etc.

However I do not think it is exporting correctly, and I do not want there to be the quotes (and yes I know this is standard but I do not want them) Also I want the header from the original csv to be applied to the child csvs and its not being applied.

sorry if theres a better way to format the code still new here

Answer (score 0):

Here is where I suggest the awesomeness of the Switch cmdlet. It compares something against multiple potential matches, and executes those matches where appropriate.

```
Switch($csv){
    {$_.column -match $target1} {$_ | Export-CSV filename1.csv -append -delimiter '|'}
    {$_.column -match $target2} {$_ | Export-CSV filename2.csv -append -delimiter '|'}
    {$_.column -match $target3} {$_ | Export-CSV filename3.csv -append -delimiter '|'}
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Being new to powershell I didn't know there was a switch like in Java. Is there any efficient way to get rid of the quotes around each field?

Comment: Not very well. It gets a lot more complicated if you do. You either have to load the file at the end and replace '","' with ',' or use convertto-csv, pipe to out-string (I think, might be able to skip that bit), replace the same thing in a ForEach loop, then pipe to Out-File -append.

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = import-csv $csvfile
$data | ?{$_.val -eq $criteria1} | export-csv -path "File1.csv"
$data | ?{$_.val -eq $criteria2} | export-csv -path "File2.csv"
```